NLP model for word recovery (analogy to BERT, but letters)
I am working on solving the problem of restoring words in text where some letters are missing. For example (restore words where vowels are removed): Hll wrld -> Hello world n ltrntv ssssmnt sggsts -> An alternative assessment suggests
Can you please suggest what pre-trained models I can use to solve this problem or maybe there are some articles that describe similar problems? I know it's similar to BERT, but BERT predicts the word, not the letters.
